# Embed google trends chart in google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

is there a way to embed a google trend chart from Google Trend service into a google drive document?

I see the option ***embed*** there but it gives you a JS to put on an html document. I'm looking more to embed it in a document in google docs, maybe with the Script Editor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The google script docs says you can't add iframe (the embed snippet is an iframe). Your best option is to screenshot it.